# Populate paypal form according to image clicked

Tags: jquery, paypal

I want to populate a paypal form based on the user clicking on images.

```
$('a.thumbnail').click(function(){
var src = $(this).attr('href');

if (src != $('img#largeImg').attr('src').replace(/\?(.*)/,'')){
    $('img#largeImg').stop().animate({
        opacity: '0'
    }, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', src+'?'+Math.floor(Math.random()*(10*100)));
    }).load(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: '1'
        });
    });
}
return false;
});
```

There are 2 sets of images, the user selects the colors he wants and according to the choices the selection in the paypal menu will change. for example - color1=black, color2=Brown

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="FEM2HYYCALHEE">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Chassis">Chassis</td></tr><tr><td><select       name="os0">
<option value="Black">Black </option>
<option value="Copper">Copper </option>
<option value="Gold">Gold </option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Lens">Lens</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os1">
<option value="Green">Green </option>
<option value="Grey">Grey </option>
<option value="Brown">Brown </option>
<option value="Amber">Amber </option>
<option value="Yellow">Yellow </option>
</select> </td></tr>
```

The dropdown menu does not have to be visible, preferably after the user clicks on the images he will click "buy now" and the colors will be updated. [See the current version of the page.](http://cliponexpress.com/test/mosaicex/test2.html)

Any suggestions?

Comment: So are you asking how to dynamically update the contents of the dropdown menus? If not, then what are you asking?

Comment: Yes, or even get rid of the dropdown menu, so that by clicking on the images black (chassis) and Grey (lens) than "buy now", the paypal form will be populated with these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for this is to make the color options hidden values, then update them in your click event, more less like this:

Form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="FEM2HYYCALHEE">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Chassis">Chassis</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="os0" type="hidden" name="os0" value="Black">
                <div id="os0_text">Black</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Lens">Lens
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="os1" type="hidden" name="os1" value="Green">
                <div id="os1_text">Green</div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#os0").val("Copper");
$("#os0_text").text("Copper");
```

Comment: Did, I apologize for taking so long.